# Deleting files from sub-folders if they exist in the closed folder

Tags: perl, perl-module

First off, I'm not a perl programmer, but I know enough to be dangerous...

I purchased an auction script which has problems which the seller of the script refuses to deal with.

There is an auctiondata folder which holds all the category folders including a closed folder when an item sells. When an item is posted it goes into one of the category folders, and when it sells, it IS SUPPOSED to be moved into the closed folder, but instead a copy is moved into the closed folder with the original file left in it's category folder.

This causes software errors until the offending file is deleted from the category folder.

So I was wondering if someone could help me with a script which searches all category folders, and any files which the file name matches a file in the closed folder would be deleted.

I have made attempts on my own and they all have failed.

The code on the buyit.pl page is as follows...

```
############################################## 
# Sub: Close Auction now 
# This sets an item's status to closed. 

sub closebuyit { 
  if ($form{'CATEGORY'},$form{'ITEM'} ne $config{'closedir'}) { 
      if ($config{'closedir'}) {
          umask(000); # UNIX file permission junk 
          mkdir("$config{'basepath'}$config{'closedir'}", 0777) unless (-d "$config{'basepath'}$config{'closedir'}"); 
          print "Please notify the site admin that this item cannot be copied to the closed directory even though it is closed.\n" 
              unless &movefile("$config{'basepath'}$form{'CATEGORY'}/$form{'ITEM'}.dat", "$config{'basepath'}$config{'closedir'}/$form{'CATEGORY'}$form{'ITEM'}.dat"); 

          unlink("$config{'basepath'}askseller/$form{'ITEM'}.dat");
          unlink("$config{'basepath'}$config{'countdir'}/$form{'ITEM'}.dat");
      }
      else { 
          print "Please notify the site admin that this item cannot be removed even though it is closed.\n" unless unlink("$config{'basepath'}$form{'CATEGORY'}/$form{'ITEM'}.dat"); 
      }
   }
}

################################################
1;
```

This is supposed to move the file from the category folder to the closed folder, but doesn't. The permissions on the folders are 755, but the file created inside is 644.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you get any of those prints ("_Please notify ..._")?  Any output?  Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should add error handling to the two unlink lines:

```
unlink("$config{'basepath'}askseller/$form{'ITEM'}.dat")
    or die "Error $! deleting $config{'basepath'}askseller/$form{'ITEM'}.dat";
unlink("$config{'basepath'}$config{'countdir'}/$form{'ITEM'}.dat")
    or die "Error $! deleting $config{'basepath'}$config{'countdir'}/$form{'ITEM'}.dat";
```

That will crash your script, but you'll get the exact error message which could led to the final solution.

Here is a start for a cleanup script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
use strict;
use warnings;

# Read the files from the closed directory
# Quick exit the script if no files could be found
opendir my $closed_dh,'/path/to/closed' or die "$! opening closed dir";
my %closed_files =
    # Use each file ($_) as key with a fixed value of 1
    (map { $_ => 1 } readdir($closed_dh)) or exit;
closedir $closed_dh;

# Loop through a list of directories
for my $dir ('/path/to/other_dir1','..dir2','..dirN') {
    opendir my $search_dh,$dir or die "$! opening $dir";
    # Loop through all files in one directory
    for my $file (readdir($search_dh)) {
        # Remove file if it exists in the list of closed files
        unlink $dir.'/'.$file or die "Error $! deleting $dir/$file"
            if $closed_files{$file};
    }
}
```

Just untested source to start with. All Perl commands are found on http://perldoc.perl.org/, more information is on http://perlmaven.com and http://learn.perl.org

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sebastian, I created a test file - move1.pl and this is the code inside...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
use strict;
use warnings;

# Read the files from the closed directory
# Quick exit the script if no files could be found
opendir my $closed_dh,'/home/users/web/b1262/moo.mybidszcom/cgi-bin/1/closed' or die "$! opening closed dir";
my %closed_files =
# Use each file ($_) as key with a fixed value of 1
(map { $_ => 1 } readdir($closed_dh)) or exit;
closedir $closed_dh;

# Loop through a list of directories
for my $dir ('/home/users/web/b1262/moo.mybidszcom/cgi-bin/1','..dir2','..dirN') {
opendir my $search_dh,$dir or die "$! opening $dir";
# Loop through all files in one directory
for my $file (readdir($search_dh)) {
    # Remove file if it exists in the list of closed files
    unlink $dir.'/'.$file or die "Error $! deleting $dir/$file"
        if $closed_files{$file};
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it didn't work and I have this error from the server logs.

0160429T101358: mybidsz.com/cgi-bin/move1.pl 
Error Is a directory deleting /home/users/web/b1262/moo.mybidszcom/cgi-bin/1/. at /home/users/web/b1262/moo.mybidszcom/cgi-bin/move1.pl line 19.

Inside if folder 1 is the Antiques18 folder, and inside that folder is a file named 1463148060.dat.

Inside folder 1 is a closed folder, and inside that folder is also a file named 1463148060.dat along with other file names.

My hope is to find a solution and then incorporate it at the end of the buyit.pl code...

Comment: The categories folder where I'm having the problems has these permissions in filezilla... [link](http://www.mybidsz.com//auction-images/error.png)